# Hide an Image in itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

What I am trying to achieve is to hide the image (either by opacity or transparency) using itextsharp. So far the image is being show as below:

```
  string webURL = "X:/XXXXXX/web.png";
  iTextSharp.text.Image webIcon = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(webURL);
 webIcon.Annotation = new Annotation(0,0,0,0, "http://www.xxxxx.com");
            webIcon.ScaleAbsolute(35f, 35f);
            webIcon.SetAbsolutePosition(227,23);
            webIcon.Transparency = new int[] {0,0 };
            //state.FillOpacity = 0.2f;
            //webIcon.GrayFill = 0.2f;
            doc.Add(webIcon);
```

How do I change the transparency so the image's visibility is null?

Comment: shouldn't transparency be set to a high value to basically hide it?

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi  even tried with {100,100};

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PdfGState`. In your case:

```
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
document.Open();

string webURL = "http://www.apache.org/foundation/press/kit/feather.png";
Image webIcon = Image.GetInstance(webURL);
webIcon.Annotation = new Annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, "http://www.google.com");
webIcon.ScaleAbsolute(35f, 35f);
webIcon.SetAbsolutePosition(227, 23);
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContentUnder;
canvas.SaveState();
PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
state.FillOpacity = 0.6f; // THIS is where you set opacity
canvas.SetGState(state);
canvas.AddImage(webIcon);
canvas.RestoreState();  

document.Close();
```

Hope it helps